# Parsing xml using MSP and node.js

Tags: node.js, msp

I have a http request which contains xml element/attribute. I am using MSP and trying to parse the xml in the request body. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried using an XML parser? Go to npmjs.org and search for "xml parser", you'll get dozens of options. Also, which "msp" are you referring to? The "multiwii serial protocol" module? The tag you added refers to Windows installer patch files? More details would be helpful, plus some indication of what you've already tried.

Comment: I am using multi-proxy-server. I am facing problem because the xml is embedded in the http request body itself.And I do not have any idea how to get the xml from the request and parse it.